# Managing rest web app hostname urls in tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

This question might have been asked before as it is quite a common exercise, but I am not sure what to search with.

I have a rest client app hosted on one instance of Tomcat and a rest server hosted on a different tomcat instance on another hostname. This works well, but currently I have the hostname hardcoded in the java classes. How can I parameter-ize the host name inside the rest client so that it allows for a future change without restarting the tomcat on which the rest client is hosted ?

Comment: reasonable question  - for which I would like a better answer really - so I don't get why it's at -1, +1 for me but I'll keep searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of solutions you could employ including (but not limited to):

1. look up the server hostname in a properties or xml file on the client server (each time you want to make a REST call)
2. provide a mechanism in the client app to configure the server hostname and store it in memory
3. look up the server hostname in a directory such as LDAP or AD or in a database (each time you want to make a REST call)

You could employ a caching mechanism if you don't want to look up the value every time - perhaps once it is read it only expires after a number of seconds/minutes, or after a number of calls.

Answer (score 1):

A quite common technique to pass environment variables and even hostname is define a System variable that you could read using  **java.lang.System.getenv()** or **java.lang.System.getProperty()** if you are using Maven once your application startup read this variable in a static class of constants so the value will be set at the beginning and remain until the end of the application there other techniques that involve, web.xml but to keep it simple this will work. Just add the var to the enviroment and read it.

Comment: But the OP wants to be able to change the server hostname without restarting Tomcat.

Comment: Yes it will as the call to the System can be done in any part or the code is kind of dynamic it you use that approach

Comment: But your answer says it will be read at the beginning and remain until the end of the application. The OP doesn't want this - they want to change the variable before the end of the application.

Comment: If you want, I mean if you dont read again it will remain the same value, but you should read again every time that you want to check if there is change, it depends on the logic and purpose but is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the host name in arguments during client process startup and then read those arguments using System.getProperty("hostName").